# Predict negative numbers in time series forcast

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to use LSTM for time series forecasting.
In all tutorials online the numbers in the data are positive numbers.
Also in all tutorials to normalize the training and testing data MinMaxScaler is use to put the output between 0 to 1.
How can I predict negative numbers / normalize the data if I have negative numbers.
All features are positive number but the numbers I want to predict can be both positive and negative.
Ex: 1.221, 1.223, 1.293 prediction should be 0.07; next 1.223, 1.293, 1.248 prediction should be -0.045.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a few options

1. output*2-1

pretty self-explanatory, 0.3 would be 0.6-1 = -0.4; 0.6 would be 1.2-1 = 0.2 etc.

2. Use an activation function that outputs negative numbers.

there are numerous activation functions that outputs numbers other than 0-1, for example, `tanh` outputs a number between -1 and 1.

[This](https://towardsdatascience.com/activation-functions-neural-networks-1cbd9f8d91d6) article covers a few activation functions that you can choose from.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Kenivia, thank you. I know that the example was something simple that could be easily be resolved with simple math (it was a just a simple example to give an idea )